# webrtc signalling server in C# dot net

Tags: c#, flutter, webrtc

I have a flutter app, I would like to have a voip call and chat in my app. So I found a sample app in webrtc flutter for voip call(https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc-demo), but there it is mentioning as I require TURN server and signalling server. I need a signalling server in C# dot net. Can anyone please help in telling me what all I need to do to set up the signalling and Turn server? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: This gives you clear idea about signalling server, you can write your signalling server with c# or nodejs or any other language - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling


This is the most popular open source Turn Server - https://github.com/coturn/coturn

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I am going through it and I still have doubt as where to use this TURN server and how to use it. I will go through this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very nice article explaining the roles of the servers:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/

Besides that, you can develop your own Signaling Server (which is not that complicated) or uses a product to do that. The article above has it all.